# Simplest proof about number of arithmetic sequences in set

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set $A = \lbrace1,2,3,\ldots,n\rbrace$, where $n \leq 2^{k}$. What is the simplest way to proof that number of arithmetic sequences with lenght $k$ from set $A$ is $< n^2/2$ ?

Comment: The strict inequality is not true. Take $k=1$ and $n=2$. Then $A=\{1,2\}$ so you have $2$ different arithemetic sequences with length $1$ but 2 is not strictly less than $2^2/2=2$.

Comment: Assume that $n$ is big enough. For example : let's say that $n > 7$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $n-j(k-1)$ length $k$ arithmetic sequences that increment by $j$. So the total number is

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n/(k-1)} n-j(k-1) \;\;<  \;\;\;\sum_{j=1}^{n/2} n \;\; =\;\; \frac{n^2}{2}$$

where we used $k\geq 3$ since $n>7$. Other than that, the $n \leq 2^k$ is a red herring.